# Array , kind of, with sums of array products, sort of, generating new array

Tags: excel, vba, function, lookup

I have a data set (columns: ten names, name_J; j=1 to jMax=10).  This is a model, each row shows the progressive changes across columns, over rows (time)

The calculation for the next row depends on an awkward calculation

For each J th cell in the next row:

```
= the sum of these TEN products (n = 1-->nMax = jMax = 10)
     the product of:  
          a: the value from the n-th column in the prior row
               TIMES  
          b: a table lookup: (n th row of the J th column)
```

(In writing this out, I m seeing how I would iterate this in VBA code)

In each cell, I could write out all these all products, once for each cell in the next row, but it seems awkward and error prone, tedious and not easily amended to change/expand jMax=nMax.

For some reason, I think there is a dsum or array formula calculation *or something* that accomplishes this calculation in each cell, without having to type out explicitly the extended calculation.

With that better way, I could change the number of N columns in the future (and therefore the identical number of n rows and j columns in the lookup table)

But going back to VBA:  Is this better done by scripting the iteration as a functional reference, directly, rather than using native index/lookup.   How would I create/call/that functional reference.  I assume something like this (in each cell), with the appropriate ranges defined in the spreadsheet (so the macro could pull in the spreadsheet max/min, table names, etc.)

```
= myNewMacro ( j, refToJMax, refToTable )
```

Comment: Hey John.  The way this entire question is worded is very confusing. Can you give an example of what the input/output would look like? That may help clear things up.

Comment: "In writing this out, I'm seeing how I would iterate this in VBA code" - if so then consider updating your post to use actual code instead of pseudo-code.  That should clarify the steps involved.

Answer (score 0):

I ve settled down on this function:

```
= sumproduct ( .... )
```

I still have to type one function for each cell, but the editing was simpler, but haven't thought how to use array formula's.

@tim williams, @user127480 i think that finding this solution with function made this question, as posed, not a worthy question , so i will think on it and either edit or remove the question.

Thanks